# Changing a visitor permission using Django Sessions

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have a Django application with a number of polls. There is no option to register on my website as a user. I want to allow a visitor to vote on a specific poll only once every seven days.

This is how I am changing the visitor permission in my **ajax.py** file

```
@dajaxice_register
def update_disable(request, song_pk):
    #update votes
    request.session['has_voted'] = True
    request.session.set_expiry(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=7))
    return dajax.json()
```

This is how I'm disabling the button in my template

```
{% if perms.hunt.has_voted %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">
      Vote as Favourite
    </button>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="update(this);">
      Vote as Favourite
    </button>
{% endif %}
```

But even after voting my code goes to the else part in the template. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what's wrong is that you are saving the flag into session, but for some reason you're trying to read `perms.hunt.has_voted` (this checks, if user hunt has permission to vote, but **not** if he already voted or not..), which is a value coming from permission app. It has nothing to do with session.

You need to access the session value from your template:

```
{% if request.session.has_voted %}
...
```

This will check if currently logged in user already voted, so if `has_voted` is `False` **or** the key doesn't exist, then user will be able to vote.

Comment: Oh, I had misunderstood the tutorial. Thanks a lot.